# How do autocomplete suggestions work?

Tags: autocomplete

For example, if you type something in upper-right google/yahoo search box in firefox there will be some kind 'suggested auto complete' sort of thing.

Another example is in youtube search box and Stackoverflow tags edit box just below this question preview. How do they work? What technology behind 'em?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's done with the use of AJAX, this site has a nice tutorial on it:
[AJAX Suggest Tutorial](http://www.dynamicajax.com/fr/AJAX_Suggest_Tutorial-.html), and the [WaybackMachine version, as website seems down](https://web.archive.org/web/20170129160828/www.dynamicajax.com/fr/AJAX_Suggest_Tutorial-.html).

A database with keywords and a bit of code is all there is to it as far as I know.

I'm learning how to use it right now actually, for work. :)

Another resource is [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp).  They have covered it as well.

Comment: I understand this is an answer from 9 years ago, but it's a perfect example of why one should not just link a tutorial. Now that site is down :( and this question is #1 in `how autocomplete works`

Comment: Edited in the internet archives version, thanks for the heads up! I don't think it's a good idea to include an enitre tutorial into an answer though - copyrights aside - because there are a lot of AJAX tutorials out there and there might be better ones than this 9 year old one :)

Comment: No, it's NOT ajax... it is ulra fast... they must be doing something else

Comment: @MartinZvarík : Probably Python or Node over websockets like socketio. I'm learning Python now and besides Node(which I know well), it is the fastest backend language I've seen. It's almost instantaneous.

Answer (score 11):

> What technology behind 'em?

In case you are wondering which data structure is being used underneath then its called "**trie**" and for using less space compared to tries you can use **"DAFSA"**

> How do they work?

both are implemented as a tree, where each node of tree corresponds to one character in a string and the character which appears before is parent of character which appears later e.g. The strings "tap", "taps", "top", and "tops" stored in a Trie (left) and a DAFSA (right),so as you begin to type tap..the tree is traversed based on the characters typed and shows the suggestions based on some weight assigned to each word, weight may be assigned based on usage frequency of the word.

[image: The strings "tap", "taps", "top", and "tops" stored in a Trie (left) and a DAFSA (right), EOW stands for End-of-word.]

Looking up string in worst case is O(m) time where m is the length of string.

Image is being referenced from the wikipedia articel : [DAFSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_acyclic_finite_state_automaton),[trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)

Answer (score 4):

They use JavaScript to normally:

- Look at a local array of all possible values
- Request another page (i.e. /autocomplete.php?q=partialText) in the background.
- Call a webservice.

When the JavaScript has the list of entries to show it modifies the page to show the autocomplete box.

If you want to put an autocomplete box on your website I have used and found the following to be very good. It is also based on the popular jQuery framework.

[jQuery autocomplete plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/)

Answer (score 3):

It's quite simple.

Client side:

1. Grab keystrokes in form field
2. On keystroke make an AJAX request to server

   1. If another keystroke is entered immediately, cancel current AJAX request as it is obsolete now
   2. Make a new AJAX requested with updated characters in form field
3. Show server response to client

Server side:

1. All words are already bucketed alphabetically
2. If client request comes in for "ove" find all words starting with ove, ordered by popularity
3. Return top matches to client

Answer (score 1):

There's an excellent open-source Country selector in the *Smashing Magazine* article (link below) which includes a discussion of the **usability challenges** with **plain autocomplete** solutions, and fixes them.

While I'm UX, not Dev, I'm certain a clever developer could adapt this open-source code to handle other kinds of selections—not just the names of countries. :)

- [The article that describes the usability issues that this selector resolves](http://uxdesign.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/10/redesigning-the-country-selector/).
- [The demo and open-source download](http://baymard.com/labs/country-selector). Try it!

Disclaimer: I have no connection to the folks who made this Country selector. I just happen to know about it, and I like to share information about Usability with developers, FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

There's as many answers to this as there are different implementations of them. Our AutoCompleter which you can see a sample of in [Stacked](http://stacked.ra-ajax.org/) works by raising an event which then is handled in the codebehind of the .ASPX page from which you populate a ControlCollection with whatever controls you wish. We're however in Stacked only using Literal controls with Text content being anchor links. But we could add up checkboxes or images if we wanted to...

If you're on ASP.NET our AutoCompleter is a great place to start. If you're on "something else" then probably ScriptAculous AutoCompleter is another nice place to start...

Answer (score 0):

i also have been recently working on autocomplete feature and we used lucene to index the text to be shown in autocomplete. Searching is fast with lucene. Somethings to look at when working with autocomplete data:

1. Freshness of suggestions,
2. Dependency on the long term data,
3. Regional dependency,
4. Language dependency

Answer (score 0):

### Update 2022

The marked answer is a little outdated. Suggestions autocomplete seems like magic on the surface but really what it is under the hood is

- fast asynch communication and
- searching through a list of keywords

Send a string to your database then return response in JSON to loop/iterate through. Then repeat as user types.

One good example is done with [YELP Fusion](https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v3/autocomplete).

Below is example with small library autocomplete.js

```js
$(function () {
var availableTags = [
"ActionScript",
"AppleScript",
"Asp",
"BASIC",
"C",
"C++",
"Clojure",
"COBOL",
"ColdFusion",
"Erlang",
"Fortran",
"Groovy",
"Haskell",
"Java",
"JavaScript",
"Lisp",
"Perl",
"PHP",
"Python",
"Ruby",
"Scala",
"Scheme"
];
$(".sbx-custom__input").autocomplete({
source: availableTags
});
});
```

```html
<!--jqueryui-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<!--autocompletejs-->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tarekraafat/autocomplete.js@10.2.6/dist/autoComplete.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tarekraafat/autocomplete.js@10.2.6/dist/css/autoComplete.min.css">


<!--input-->
<input class="sbx-custom__input" autocomplete="on" required="required" placeholder="autocomplete...">
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the simple example from my code(using jquery + jquery ui). first i requested all data with ajax that i prefixed to inbox then i clicked one of them and so it redirects to another action succesfully.

```
        $("#Name").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                var prefix = { Name: request.term};
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("FilterMastersByName", "JsonResult")',
                    data: JSON.stringify(prefix),
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return item;
                        }))
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            },
            select: function (e, i) {
                var abc=i.item.val;
                let a = document.createElement('a');
                a.href = `/Home/GetMasterById?masterId=${abc}`;
                a.click();

            },
            minLength: 1
        });
    });
```

Dont forget  setFilterMastersByName action to httppost and GetMasterById to httpget

Answer (score -1):

[Here is one for MooTools](http://digitarald.de/project/autocompleter/).